# php submit button not working while using explode function

Tags: php

Following is the code where I have called a php function through a button. But the button which I am clicking is not triggering the function.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li style="padding:10px;">

                        <button type="submit" name="imp" id="subDownload" class="btn btn-success subDownload" value="download"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Send Email</button> 

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

              <div id="address" >
                    <h4>To:</h4>
                    <textarea id="address" name="invoice_address_to" class="form-control input-noshow" rows="6" cols="35">
Some Company
Address 1
Address 2
Zipcode
State
Country
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>


</form>


<?php 

function test()
{
print_r (explode('/n',invoice_address_to));
}

if (isset($_POST['imp'])) {
        test();

    }
?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What is `invoice_address_to` and how do you think what is it's value?

Comment: @u_mulder its a textarea...and I am trying to explode its value by '/n'

Comment: Your button doesn't refer to the function. Furthermore, it's only possible to refer to a javascript function, not a PHP function. You can only perform PHP code when the page is initialized. This is basic knowledge, you should try to start with some tutorials.

Comment: @u_mulder...i already have used if (isset($_POST['imp'])) {
        test();

    }

Comment: @Casper pressing button initiates `POST` request. And OP checks if `isset($_POST)`, all is fine.

Comment: Also try `<input type="submit"` instead of `<button type="submit"` and remove inner span from it.

Comment: @u_mulder have done the following...<input type="submit" name="imp" id="subDownload" class="btn btn-success subDownload" value="Send Email"></button> still no luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your posted text is not submitting to function test. You can do it by updating your php code with following code

```
<?php 

function test($string)
{
    #print_r(explode('/n',$string));
    var_dump($string);
}

if (isset($_POST['imp']))
{
    test($_POST['invoice_address_to']);
}
?>
```

Comment: try to `var_dump($string)` in your test function

Comment: no luck...can you please guide me why the button is not triggered...atleast it shud triggered...

Comment: `var_dump` anything in `if (isset($_POST['imp']))` block